Merge two Laravel Eloquent queries
I have a Laravel-Project and use:
User.php as a model
public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id');
    }

public function feedPosts() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Post::Class, Follow::Class, 'user_id', 'user_id', 'id', 'followeduser');
    }

UserController.php as a Controler
public function showCorrectHomepage(User $username) {
    $this->getSharedData($username);
    return view('homepage-feed', ['posts' => auth()->user()->feedPosts()->latest()->paginate(10)]); 
   }

homepage-feed.blade.php as a View
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <a href="/post/{{$post->id}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <img class="avatar-tiny" src="{{$post->findUser->avatar}}" />
    <strong>{{$post->title}}</strong> 
    <span class="text-muted small">
    vom {{$post->created_at->format('d.m.Y')}} geschrieben um {{$post->created_at->format('H:i')}} Uhr
    </span>
 </a>
@endforeach

Everything works great.

The 'feedPosts' function in the User.php model returns posts that a user has subscribed to.

The 'posts' function in the User.php model returns the posts that a user has written.

Currently, the posts that a user has subscribed to are displayed in the homepage-feed view.

The goal is to display the posts that a user has subscribed to AND written themselves.


I have not yet managed to combine both queries. However, I am also a Laravel beginner.
I have tried
public function showCorrectHomepage(User $username) {
    $this->getSharedData($username);
    $usersposts = auth()->user()->posts()->latest()->get();
    $usersabos = auth()->user()->feedPosts()->latest()->get();
    $allposts = $userposts->union($userabos)->paginate(10);
    return view('homepage-feed', ['posts' => $allposts); 
   }

but there are always errors that I don't understand.
I would be grateful for any help. Thank you very much!
Best regards Dennis

I have discovered that this is probably due to the fact that the 'laravel_through_key' column is additionally included in the “feedPosts” query, and therefore the union() function does not work because the columns of the two queries are not identical.
I think the right way would be to get rid of it and then use the union() function? or am I barking up the wrong tree?? However, I don't know how to merge individual columns.

but there are always errors ... and those errors would be?? (append to the question)
